# Advertising API for Java ME applications?

Tags: java-me, ads, admob, ads-api

I know [AdMob](http://www.admob.com/appdevs) is not for Java ME.
Do you know any other advertising API or services that can be used in Java ME application?

It might be really good if I can earn some money with my free Java ME applications.

Comment: I found http://adfonic.com/ supports advertising from Java ME application. Please let me know if you know any other services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://adfonic.com/ Adfonic is what can I find now. 
You can follow it's instruction from http://developer.adfonic.com/index.php/Getting_Started to allow mobile advertising from Java ME application.